# Python: How to include the exe file of a script in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python by myself using Zed A.Shaw's book Learn Python the hard way.
At [exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html). I'am supposed to create a project skeleton (i.e. create a setup.py file, create modules, and so). Then make a project.

I have to put a script in my bin directory that is runnable for my system. I wrote the simple `Hello World!` script turned it into an .exe file using **cxfreeze**.

However when I try to install my setup.py file (i.e. By typing `python setup.py install` in the cmd), I can't install this .exe file instead I can only install the script script.py
How can I install this exe file.
This is my setup.py file:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description':  'First project',#ex46
    'author':  'author',#
    'url':  '',#N/A
    'download_url':  '',#N/A
    "author_email":  "author_email@email.com"
    'versio':  '3.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['skeleton\quiz46','skeleton\\tests'],
    'scripts':  ['skeleton\\bin\helloscript.py','skeleton\\bin\helloscript.exe'],
    'name':  'quiz46'
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError
```

I have also tried putting skeleton\bin\helloscript.exe but that gives me a similiar Error!

My OS is Windows 7, and I am using Python 3.1.

Again what I want is for the setup.py to install my .exe file too not just it's script.

Comment: When showing an error, include the entire traceback you got, it helps to diagnose problems.  Also, you seem to have edited the setup.py to remove identifying information?  It's possible the error was in that data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the `script` option is meant to handle anything but text files. If you have a look at the source code for [distribute (aka setuptools)](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/wiki/Home), the `write_script` command will try to `encode('ascii')` the contents if it's anything other than a python script AND if you are using Python 3. Your `cxfreeze` exe is a binary file, not a text file, and is likely causing this to choke.

The easier option to get `setuptools` to include a executable script in the installation process is to use the `entry_points` option in your `setup.py` rather than `scripts`:

```
entry_points={'console_scripts':['helloscript = helloscript:main'] }
```

The `console_script` will automatically wrap your original `helloscript.py` script and create an `exe` (on Windows) and install it into your Python's `Script` directory. No need to use something like `cxfreeze`.

Comment: But I tried putting entry_points in my setup.py file.I put it once in config. And once outside of config.But it still gives me the same result.I think I'doing it wrong!

Comment: Sounds like you are still trying to use your `cxfreeze` binary file. You need to remove reference it from your `setup.py`.  The `entry_points` `console_scripts` are meant to point to callables within your original python script. Read the docs on setuptools entry_points (http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html?highlight=console_script#automatic-script-creation) to figure it out. That's what Zed wants you to do. :-)

Comment: Finally worked!Got my hey.exe file using entry_points,console_scripts,But I still have one problem,entry_points creates this file in my c:\python31\scripts file. Can I change this path.